# How to override a *{list style:none} property

Tags: css, list

I have the following declaration that is not editable (platform restriction):

```
*{list-style:none;}
```

And I want to make a list with dots.
This does not work:

```
#id{
list-style-type:circle !important; 
}
```

Can someone tell me how to override the first declaration?
I was under the impression that in css * is overwritten by #id and that !important overwrites everything. Why this does not work?
I made a jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/7AcA9/1/

Thanks!

Comment: It was ul, now I understand it should be li. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the rule to `#id li`.

The `list-style` property applies to list-items `<li>`, not the container `<ul>`, so the `*` rule overrides it. The reason that `#id` works normally is because the property is inherited.

You can also remove the `!important` modifier too.

Comment: To elaborate, `!important` is not required because `#id li` has a higher selector precedence than `*`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `li` after the ID selector,

```
#id li {
    list-style-type:circle; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`#mam` (or `#id` per your question) does not select `li`.  It only selects `ul`.  `*` selects the `li` and the `list-style-type` property is overridden.  You could use `#mam li`.